# Apk updated version cannot be installed

Tags: android, installation, apk

I took a project from github and developed a few functionalities that I needed for my own use. 
I created a new apk after finishing those, the phone recognizes it as being a new version of the existing app, but it fails installation after a few seconds of *"Installing"*. *App not installed*. 
Links to printscreens:
 https://gyazo.com/93b94183572f139d9a07b937c5a1eed2
 https://gyazo.com/bdbee5e182f7e8d69ee00c7daac88cf3

I've displayed my current versionCode and it was something about 10230000. Tried to change it in gradle to 10230008, still fails. Changed my app versionName as well without any positive result.

The initial version of module gradle was:

```
    ...
    versionName rootProject.ext.versionName 
    versionCode rootProject.ext.versionCode
    buildConfigField 'String', 'REALM_ENCRYPTION_KEY', "\"${rootProject.ext.realmEncryptionKey}\""
    ...
```

Project gradle:

```
...
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
ext {
versionName = project['version.major'] + '.' +
        project['version.minor'] + '.' +
        project['version.patch']


versionCode = (project['version.major'].toInteger() * 1000 * 1000 * 1000) +
        (project['version.minor'].toInteger() * 1000 * 1000) +
        (project['version.patch'].toInteger() * 1000) +
        project['version.build'].toInteger()

bugsnagAPIKey = System.getenv('BUGSNAG_API_KEY') ?: ''
realmEncryptionKey = System.getenv('REALM_ENCRYPTION_KEY') ?: 'ZX06poC7a96dL9,FR_9|Ww<2%]?4Ij(3wR3DmyNj0[{(,8g%jX2{03P45_p`N6|2'
}  
...
```

#### Why can't the app be installed even though it is recognized as being an update?

Comment: Please add some logcat of installing, or at least the `pm install -r` command output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wants to update this application from the previous **binary release** (that is, you took this `.apk` from GitHub directly, and install it into your phone, compared to build the previous version from source code), then you have two choices:

1. Ask the original packager (author?) to pack your source for you.
2. Uninstall the previous APK, then install the new one.
3. <del>Crack the signing key.</del>

The easiest way is obviously the second one.

*In my memory, the core of original question is the signing key of that `.apk` file.*

Answer (score 1):

Try in android studio:
Go to `File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run`
and turn it of.

[image]

And try in you android phone:

```
Settings -> Apps & notifications -> See all x apps ->
```

Search your app and click on it and do `FORCE STOP` and `UNINSTALL`.

Comment: Uninstalling would remove my initial configuration saved on the original app, but I guess it's the only way

Comment: Hi @Ncs if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to update the app, the excited version on the device must have the same signature as the new version, otherweise it will not being installed. The ones you can try to do is uninstall the app and then reinstall it, then they will work well.

It may also be because you do not have enough expression for the new update.

Comment: You mean signature key that I am asked for when I build the apk ? I don't have the original signature key, since the app was taken initially from github

Comment: @Ncs if you take this app **binary** directly from GitHub, then you have only one method to solve this question, just uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: No, I mean that both apks most have same key, otherweise you can't install the app